# How can I determine the average date against multiple date records?

Tags: formula, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I currently have hire dates of multiple agents that report to a specific supervisor. When I take a cross tab of their hire dates listed individually and place it in excel, excel will let you highlight them for an average date.

I am trying to recreate this functionality in Tableau using a calculated field, however it is not providing me with a date matching the excel check.

Hire date is obviously in a date time data type. I’ve tried formulas such as AVG(FLOAT([hire date] and also tried to do some variations of placing it over the count of hire dates. Just to reinforce, I’m not trying to place these dates against anything configurable, just looking to get an average on a couple of dates that can have repeats (training classes all same day).

I have 5:30PM brain right now so I may solve this tomorrow morning but any insight you all have would be great.

Comment: There's more than one way to interpret what "average date" means. Since your goal is to replicate what Excel does, I'd start by finding out exactly what Excel does.

Comment: Yeah good points. So I found it extremely difficult to search for what it does since everything wants to point me to dates against a single point. 

Then you had me thinking. I may be able to just get agent tenure by days against the current date. Then just average those together for an average team tenure. It’s a bit more than I would like to do, and it won’t display it as a date which was the goal. Hopefully others will have some more insight into how excel does it.